# Changing pane background color in Animate

Tags: manipulate, customization

In the code

```
Style[#, DefaultOptions -> {Panel -> {Background -> LightBlue}}] & @
   Manipulate[ArrayPlot[CellularAutomaton[n, {{1}, 0}, {40, All}]], {n, 0, 255, 1}]
```

[image]

How to change the color of the inside white box to LightBlue as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Style[#, DefaultOptions -> {Panel -> {Background -> LightBlue}}] &@
 Manipulate[ArrayPlot[CellularAutomaton[n, {{1}, 0}, {40, All}] /. 0 -> LightBlue],
  {n, 0, 255, 1}, Method -> {"ContentAreaBackground" -> LightBlue}]
```

[image]

```
Style[#, DefaultOptions -> {Panel -> {Background -> LightBlue}}] &@
  Manipulate[Plot[Sin[n x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   Background -> LightBlue], 
  {{n, 3}, 0, 10, 1}, Method -> {"ContentAreaBackground" -> LightBlue}]
```

[image]